# Delete rows with inner join?

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I have a SQLITE database with two tables. Table A has an integer timestamp and another integer column containing a row id referring to a row in table B which has two timestamps.

I want to delete all rows in table A where it's timestamp does not lie between the two timestamps in table B, and the ROWID is equal to X.

Here is what I have at the moment but I am getting a syntax error:

```
DELETE FROM network
WHERE ROWID in (
    SELECT ROWID 
    FROM track 
    INNER JOIN network ON (track.ROWID = network.trackId) 
    WHERE network.timestamp > track.stopTime OR network.timestamp < track.startTime 
        AND network.trackId = X
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have a closing parenthesis for your subselect. Try this:

```
DELETE FROM network
WHERE ROWID in (
    SELECT ROWID 
    FROM track 
    INNER JOIN network ON (track.ROWID = network.trackId) 
    WHERE network.timestamp > track.stopTime OR network.timestamp < track.startTime 
       AND network.trackId = X
)
```

If that doesn't work, try posting your actual syntax error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. You were right, that sorted the first syntax error. Also WHERE ROWID should have been WHERE trackId, and SELECT ROWID should have been SELECT track.ROWID. The script now seems to be working. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: DELETE FROM tblRecipe
            WHERE categoryID in (
                            SELECT categoryID
                            FROM tblSubCategories
                            INNER JOIN tblRecipe ON (tblSubCategories.categoryID = tblRecipe.categoryID)
                            WHERE  tblRecipe.categoryID = 9;

Comment: whnat if you had 2 columns say rowid and something else

Comment: @PirateApp: I don't understand your question. I suggest posting a new question with details of your specific query and problem.

Comment: @Flimzy delete from network where (id1,id2) in (select id1,id2 from track ....) can this be done

Comment: As I suggested, you should ask a new question. (Although that question has probably already been asked)